# How may I remove extra white space with BorderRadius

Tags: flutter

How can I manage to remove extra white space when using border radius on a container widget. You will find a screenshot below.

[image]

Parent:

```
return Dismissible(
                  direction: DismissDirection.endToStart,
                  key: ValueKey<String>(item['sys_uuid']),
                  onDismissed: (DismissDirection direction) {
                    delOnePeople(item['sys_uuid']);
                    items.removeAt(index);
                  },
                  background: Container(
                    decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(25)),
                      color: Colors.red,
                    ),
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 15),
                    margin: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 5),
                    child: const Align(
                      alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
                      child: Icon(
                        Icons.delete,
                        color: Colors.white,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  child: PeopleCard(
                    person: Person.fromJson(item),
                    index: index,
                    savePeopleModified: savePeople,
                  ),
                );
```

From People Card child:

```
child: Container(
          decoration: const BoxDecoration(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
              Radius.circular(25),
            ),
            color: Colors.blue,
          ),
```

Comment: wrap dismissible with container and give the samer border radius

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping your container with a `ClipRRect` widget

```dart
ClipRRect(
   borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(25)),
   child: Container(/* ... */),
),
```

Comment: I did the modification but same behavious